# Merge two Dictionary into one Dictionary<A, Dictionary<B, List<C>

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

Let's say I have two type of dictionaries:

- `Dictionary<A, List<C>>`
- `Dictionary<B, List<C>>`

And I would like to merge the second one in the first one. Something like:
`Dictionary<A, Dictionary<B, List<C>>`. What would be the best way in Linq to do it ?

Thank you for helping!

--

**EDIT1:**
Consider the below example:
`

```
public enum GameCategory
{
    FPS,
    RPG,
    STRATEGY
}

public class Game
{
    // The format is: "CountryName,CompanyName,TeamName,GameName"
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public DateTime InitialReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public GameCategory Category { get; set; }
}
public class GameManager
{
    // CodeName is coming from Name once Substring applied.
    // This dictionary is just all the games grouped by this CodeName
    // eg if we have Game1 with name: "USA:Test:MyTeam:GoodGame" & Game2 with: "USA:Test:AnotherTeam:AnotherGame"
    // The codeName for both is: "USA:Test" so they are in the same list of dict1
    Dictionary<string, List<Game>> _gameByCodeName;

    // It is just a grouped by GameCategory
    Dictionary<GameCategory, List<Game>> _gameByCategory;

    // Expected output
    // The goal is just to have the two granularity in one data structure
    // In the above example it will be all the games that have the same CodeName and are in the same category     
    Dictionary<string, Dictionary<GameCategory, List<Game>>>
}
```

`

Comment: Merge using *what* criteria? The question is unclear

Comment: In any case this isn't merging. This creates a *new* construct. Somehow, somewhere entries from one dictionary are combined with entries from another. You can write a loop to do this, use two `from` clauses in a LINQ query or `join` on the join condition. "Best" can mean faster, easier to write, easier to read, with fewer allocations, all of the above or none of the above

Comment: Sorry if it is unclear.
Both dictionary have been created using the same List<C>.
Moreover, the 2 dict are some kind of different element grouped by 2 differents criterias.
For instance Dictionary<B, List<C>> is built using a field from type C (this field is B)
Dictionary<A, List<C>> is built after some operations on List<C> (the output is type A)

The final output would be to have not only one element of granularity but two - that's why I called it a merge

I can indeed try doing a double loop. but I was wondering if there is a less verbose - understandable and nicer way

Comment: Update the question and explain all that there. Concrete examples will help get an answer faster. Right now you're describing how some code works. Post the code itself instead. `Some kind of` and `built after` don't explain much

Comment: if you post example input, expected output and possibly code, people can get straight to answering or finding a solution. Otherwise they'll spend the time trying to guess what the actual problem is